# Failed to load the hostfxr.dll after install net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Anyone has this problem i change Pc and tried to install net core framework but vs code return this info when i tried to write
dontet --info

```
Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.1.0\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x80070057
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.1.0\hostfxr.dll failed
- Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR Since the original download is no more, here's what I found on the dell forums:

[Standalone package: Microsoft Update Catalog - KB4457144](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4457144)

I had the exact same error message (apart from the directories) on **Win7** with a **newer VC++ redist** already present.

The package contains the KB2533623 that we want.
[Details of KB4457144: September 11, 2018—KB4457144 (Monthly Rollup)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4457144/windows-7-update-kb4457144)

After installation and a reboot, `dotnet new console` goes through without an error.

Dell forum source: [Microsoft Windows 7 Update KB2533623 needed to install Dell Update Package (DUP)](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln315961/microsoft-windows-7-update-kb2533623-needed-to-install-dell-update-package-dup?lang=en)

Comment: Just wanna tell you, that if you and others like you did not exist, I would have become MAC user long ago. Saved me my Sunday night...

Comment: Glad I could help. Took me a good while to hunt this file down and wanted to make sure, I can save someone else the hassle :-)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error and I checked my Web API `Program.cs` class and found that: `.UseIISIntegration()` is missing. I added it and the problem solved.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().UseIISIntegration();
}
```

Comment: For in-process, this should be `.UseIIS()` instead of `.UseIISIntegration()`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was windows7 x64 and according to this instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50

Windows 7 SP1 ESU   - Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable 64-bit / 32-bit

- KB3063858 64-bit / 32-bit
- Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011 (.NET Core 2.1 offline installer only)

There was no KB3063858 on my machine. After installation my application has started.

(I uset asp net 5)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very late but I am trying to list steps to solve this issue hope, this helps! I followed the solutions provided on this link but in my case the deployment environment was the issue. listing down the steps I followed to fix this.

1. Deploy .Net core runtime with your application if not available on target machine from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1
2. set the environment variable DOTNET_ROOT
3. the appropriate deployment path/environment SIT/UAT (in my case) to solve this (a)"Deployment Mode: Self Contained" needs to be selected in Visual studio 2019. while publishing OR (b) dotnet publish -c Release -r --self-contained true
4. in case the target machine is 64 bit or 86. C:\Program Files\dotnet OR C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet you can find the respective folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case it was because I needed to clear my publish folder first. Apparently when you first publish as 32 bit and then as 64 bit, some files remain. When publishing to a clean folder, the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

This answer fixed my issue; I had built 32 bit first, then tried 64 (which was the correct build).  After I deleted the publish folder and re-publishing, the hostfxr.dll problem stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just had to solve this one.

In the end I had to change the Application pool setting Enable 32 bit applications to False.

Answer (score -1):

Try download this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47442

After installing this, I fixed this issue.

**Edit:**
[The screenshot for this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBGEf.png)

Comment: what is "this"? the link is almost totally opaque

Comment: @starball This link is to download **Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3063858)**, I still can access this link, no idea why you can't. I add a screen shot for the link

Comment: I'm not saying I can't access it. I'm saying you should give context as to what the link is in your answer post.