# DLL load failed while executing .NET commands in cmd

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen a similar question in this site, but the solution for that did not work for me. I downloaded the .NET SDK 2.2.10 installer in my laptop( Windows 7) and after successful installation whenever I try to execute any command related to .NET on cmd, it shows the following error:

```
C:\Users\USER>dotnet --help
Failed to load the DLL from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.2.0\hostfxr.dll]
, HRESULT: 0x80070057
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\dotnet\h
ost\fxr\2.2.0\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

C:\Users\USER>
```

When I just type dotnet, it shows the following instructions:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USER>dotnet

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET Core information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

Why is this DLL not being loaded properly? 
After resolving this issue, how to compile c# programs from the command line?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you follow this advice already: *Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.*

Comment: What are the prerequisites? Where should I install them from?

Comment: There is a link directly under that message: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: It's not coming, can you post it in the comment?

Comment: here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2.0/2.2.0-download.md and your OS is Windows 7, SP1 right?

Comment: Thank You and YES

Comment: Might be an duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777065/failed-to-load-hostfxr-dll

Comment: Even after installing all dependencies, it's showing same error!

Comment: And no pending Windows Updates that needs to be installed?

Comment: or another dupe with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644730/failed-to-load-the-hostfxr-dll-after-install-net-core

Comment: Win7 is rapidly turning into the new XP.  Do run Windows Update first.  And check with IT staff, they may intentionally prevent updates from getting deployed.